# How to sequence Play Enumerators without interleaving?

Tags: scala, playframework, enumerator

Say, I have sequence of `Enumerator`s, and the aim is to run them one by one, similar to long chain of`Enumerator`s with `andThen` between them, i.e. **without** interleaving.

So, how to combine `Seq[Enumerator[T]]` into `Enumerator[T]`?

Comment: Doesn't simply reducing all the values, i.e. `val combined = enumerator_set.reduceLeft(_ andThen _)`, work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting, it seems that there is no built-in function for that. Something like that would work:

```
val enumerators: Seq[Enumerator[T]] = ...
enumerators.foldRight(Enumerator.eof[T])((st, i) => i andThen st)
```

Edit: update response after Andrew confirmed that it works.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I have crawled on the API with lens and hasn't found anything suitable.

Comment: A little addition. To make Scala compiler happy `eof` method wants to be called with explicit type parameter: `Enumerator.eof[T]`.

Comment: Yeah, I thought it would be the case but I was a bit lazy :)

Comment: At last I have tried it on the real data, and have found I want this one: ```enums.foldLeft(Enumerator.empty[T])((st, i) => st andThen i)``` - it preserves an order the way I want (that is as in the input sequence).